# Delphi 7 on Windows 8

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have installed Windows 8 on my laptop, and trying to get Delphi 7 to run.

I get the AV error:  Access Violation at address 40005A06 in MOdule 'rtl70.bpl' Read of address C08B0033

I have tried everything I can think of, even reinstalled windows 8 instead of 8.1, but the problem persists.  I have replaced the rtl70.bpl files in the SYSWOW64 and System32 files.

It has worked in the past on Win 8.1, but not this time around?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can think of nothing else to try. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you run D7 with Admin right?

Comment: Yes thank you, I did that.  I am thinking maybe my D7 installation files are compromised?

Comment: I checked Delphi 7 (Build 8.1) with WIndows 2012 Essential -- I had different errors on startup. Run in compatible mode and with Admin rights didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to your Delphi-7 shortcut right-click on it and select properties. 
Then at the top of the window select compatibility.
Then find the compatibility section, tick the box saying "Run this program in compatibility for:" and select "Windows XP(Service Pack 2)" from the drop down box. Apply these settings

I am not sure if this is the problem but this is how I run Delphi-7 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Delphi 7 on Windows 8.1 using the advice from Craig, except that I used compatibility for `Windows XP (SP 3)`. In the "Settings" section, I enabled `Disable display scaling on high DPI settings` and `Run this program as administrator`. Works well.

I have also since installed 3rd party extensions such as GEExperts and TurboPower SysTools v4.03. To get the latter to work, I had to navigate to these two registry keys:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\BorlandProjectGroup\Shell\Open] and
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DelphiPackage\Shell\Open]
and in each delete the "ddeexec" key. Then load the "S403_d70.dpk" package from within Delphi.

Hope that helps!